# Troubleshooting OSM Overpass server

Tags: overpass-api

We have installed our own OSM overpass server with planet data. It was first working ok, but after enabling data updates it slowed down significantly. CPU and disk IO usage is low. I cannot say for sure that data updates is the cause. Is there something describing how to troubleshoot it? https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Installation
has some info, but not about troubleshooting performance.

Hardware info: m4.2xlarge instance type in AWS with GP2 SSDs. GP2 = general purpose SSDs. 8 vCPUs, 31GB RAM.

`M4 instances are the latest generation of General Purpose Instances. This family provides a balance of compute, memory, and network resources, and it is a good choice for many applications.
Features:
2.3 GHz Intel Xeon® E5-2686 v4 (Broadwell) processors or 2.4 GHz Intel Xeon® E5-2676 v3 (Haswell) processors
EBS-optimized by default at no additional cost
Support for Enhanced Networking
Balance of compute, memory, and network resources
Model    vCPU    Mem (GiB)    SSD Storage (GB)    Dedicated EBS Bandwidth (Mbps)
m4.large    2     8           EBS-only            450
m4.xlarge   4    16           EBS-only            750
m4.2xlarge  8    32           EBS-only           1,000`

Comment: Can you add some details to your question to reproduce your issue? At least Overpass API version, the kind of database you run (attic/no attic), more details on your hardware, your query would be the absolute minimum. Also, what the response was before and what it looks like now. Do you use minutely updates?

Comment: Overpass server was installed about 2-3 weeks ago following wiki instructions. The directory name is osm-3s_v0.7.54. It's data only, not meta no history (attic?) Updates are daily. This is one of the queries: ```[out:json];
area(3602552450)->.aboveCityArea;
(
rel(area.aboveCityArea)[admin_level][admin_level!=6];
way(area.aboveCityArea)[admin_level][admin_level!=6];
rel(bw)[admin_level][admin_level!=6];
)->.all;
(
rel.all[name="Tate"];
rel.all[alt_name="Tate"];
);
out geom;``` If you give me instructions of now to turn on extra logging/tracong/perf profiling I can do it and send logs

Comment: I understand that you need steps to reproduce it, unfortunately I cannot spend much time on it, or to become Overpass server expert. I hoped to have a back box that is setup once and runs reliably and well. It does not seem to work that way, and I am ready to bail and try another way to access OSM data, like https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql.

Comment: The official instance runs your query in a few seconds, though it doesn't return any results (didn't check if this is intended, maybe your query is incorrect?). Anyway, you didn't mention any runtimes you measured as requested before. What was the runtime before starting the updates, and currently, what is your expectation? Also, without further details on your hardware, there's no point in doing any logging/tracing.

Comment: It takes 30 sec on my server, and before slowdown it was taking ~6 sec, it was slightly faster than on http://overpass-api.de. Let me get hardware details.

Comment: It seems getting progressively slower over time. First my tests (with 10 sec timeout) start failing, then in couple days my jobs using server start getting gateway timeout. Rebooting server brought things back to initial slow stage (10 sec timeout) and I expect in few days it will degrade again to gateway timeout.

Comment: added hardware info

Comment: Slowing down this much is completely unexpected. I think it would be best to file an issue here: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues -

Comment: Thanks! Follow up is here: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/422